# How to set the baud rate for Macs in a terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, arduino, communication, baud-rate

Is it possible to set the baud rate for Macs in a terminal? If yes, how to set the baud rate in terminal through the terminal?

I am trying to talk to the Mac using an [Arduino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) (open source microcontroller), an [XBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digi_International#Wireless) (wireless communicator) to type in the terminal through the serial monitor. The only problem I am having is the baud rate of the serial monitor and terminal are different. I can easily change the baud rate for the serial monitor in the Arduino, but I do not know what the baud rate is for the terminal in Mac.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Well what i am trying to do is talk to the mac using an arduino (open source microcontroller), an xbee (wireless comunicator) to type in terminal through the serial monitor. The only problem i am having is the baud rate of the serial monitor and terminal are different. I can easily change to baud rate in the serial monitor but i do not know how to change the baud rate in the terminal.

Comment: you should add that information to your question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On Mac OS, `stty` seemingly can only change terminal settings for an ongoing access.

It works to either:

- Access the serial interface, e.g. `cat /dev/cu.usbserial`, the default settings will be used at first. On a different terminal use `stty`, e.g. `stty -f /dev/cu.usbserial 230400` to set the baud rate, the settings of the terminal accessed before will change.
- There is a small time window after executing `stty`, in which the access can be performed with the desired parameters, e.g. `stty -f /dev/cu.usbserial 230400 & cat /dev/cu.usbserial` executes `stty`, detaches it and then immediately performs the access to the serial device.
- For one line command logging serial port `/dev/tty.usbserial-X`'s output to `cat.out` and terminating the logging by pressing `Ctrl+C`, here is the solution: `trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' SIGINT ; cat /dev/tty.usbserial-X | tee cat.out & stty -f /dev/tty.usbserial-X 115200`. You can type `Ctrl+C` to terminate logging to `cat.out`. (edited)

This only seems to work for the `/dev/cu.*` device files. I  don't know the difference from `/dev/tty.*` files.

Comment: I was looking for a solution to this problem for MONTHS! Your solution did it for me. I am using `screen` to connect to a dev board with 460800 Baud. The first way (using two terminals) you provided didn't work (`device busy`). But the second one with sending `stty` to the background did work: `stty -f /dev/cu.usbserial-141A 460800 & screen /dev/cu.usbserial-141A 460800`

Comment: I should add that `screen` or any other terminal program usually doesn't have problems to set the proper baudrate. But there seems to be a bug in OSX that normally doesn't allow to set baudrates higher than 230400. The problem is independent of the terminal program and the driver  that is used. I wrote about it [here](https://cervisial.wordpress.com/2016/02/02/using-serial-adapters-with-baudrates-230400-on-osx/). But with your second solution it is possible to use these higher baudrates. Thanks again!

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3798003?tstart=0
"(...)In OS X and other versions of UNIX, closing the serial port restores it to its default settings. (...)"

Comment: I tried this on macOS Catalina but it didn't work, maybe they changed something?

Answer (score 1):

[Minicom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minicom) is an excellent tool that does exactly what you're asking for.  You can get it using apt on ubuntu but should check this [Tutorial](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20041026113304907) out for Mac.

Keep the serial reset issue in mind if you plan on sending data to the Arduino.  see http://arduino.cc/playground/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection

Answer (score 0):

**stty 19200** or so.

Check `man stty`, you can set stop bits, speed, etc.

Comment: you cant set them this command only allows you to see them. When trying to set the baud rate i get illegal option

Comment: now checked it thru null modem cable and serial port. stty **can set** the baud rate.

Comment: That would be great, except it doesn't work:
`> stty -f /dev/tty.usbserial-A96HPNJJ speed 115200`
`9600`
`> stty -f /dev/tty.usbserial-A96HPNJJ `
`speed 9600 baud;`
`lflags: -icanon -isig -iexten -echo`
`iflags: -icrnl -ixon -ixany -imaxbel -brkint`
`oflags: -opost -onlcr -oxtabs`
`cflags: cs8 -parenb`

Comment: Sorry for the formatting problems. I couldn't get it to format terminal output.

Answer (score 0):

Surprised that no one mentioned picocom which could set higher bard rate up to 4000000.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30414080)